# get the highest value, and then filter results by class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the highest value stored between strong tags, and then filter results by class "condition ok" in jquery. Can someone help me with this problem please?

```
<div id="my_list">
  <div class="my_class">
    <div>
      <p> <strong>12</strong>
      </p>
      <p class="condition ok"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="my_class">
      <div>
        <p> <strong>10</strong>
        </p>
        <p class="condition ok"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="my_class">
        <div>
          <p> <strong>25</strong>
          </p>
          <p class="condition"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="my_class">
          <div>
            <p> <strong">20</strong>
            </p>
            <p class="condition ok"></p>
          </div>
```

Comment: To be more specific, you want the highest number from any paragraph *only* preceding a paragraph with the `ok` class ?

Comment: Also note that all those elements are nested, and not closed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some error at **HTML**.

1. You don't close `<div class='my_class'>`
2. Last **strong** element has unnecessary **double quote**

After then, Take a look at the fiddle to get the result : https://jsfiddle.net/2hf2qt2j/

---

```js
var max = -1;

$("strong").each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().next("p").is('.condition.ok'))
        max = Math.max(max, $(this).text());
});

alert(max);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_list">
  <div class="my_class">
    <div>
      <p> <strong>125</strong></p>
      <p class="condition ok"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my_class">
      <div>
        <p> <strong>10</strong></p>
        <p class="condition ok"></p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my_class">
     <div>
       <p> <strong>525</strong></p>
       <p class="condition"></p>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my_class">
     <div>
       <p> <strong>20</strong></p>
       <p class="condition ok"></p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**Update**

If strong has negative value, then take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/y09vq8p5/